# Calculate $E[C_n]$, where $C_n$ denotes the number of copies

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, expected-value

If we roll a fair die $n \ge 1$ times and we say that for $i \ge 2$ the $ith$ roll is a copy if the result is the same as the $(i−1)th$ roll. If we take for example the sequence $11433$ and the second and fifth rolls are copies. Let $C_n$ denote the number of copies.

I have to compute $E[C_n]$ and $E[C^2_n]$, where $E$ stands for the expectation.

Any help would be grateful because I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $C_n$ as $X_2 + X_3 +\cdots+X_n$ where $$X_i=\begin{cases}1&\text{if roll $i$ is a copy}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ (Roll $1$ can never be a copy.) So by linearity
$$
E(C_n) = E(X_2 + X_3 + \cdots + X_n) = E(X_2) + E(X_3) + \cdots + E(X_n).
$$
How to calculate $E(X_i)$? Since $X_i$ takes value either $1$ or $0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(X_i) &= 1\cdot P(X_i=1) + 0\cdot P(X_i=0) \\&= P(X_i=1)\\
&=P(\text{roll $i$ is a copy}).
\end{aligned}
$$
Now roll $i$ is a copy exactly when roll $i$ agrees with whatever roll came before it, so this last probability is $\frac16$.

Comment: Is it true that E[$C^2_n$] equals 1/6 also? And from that I get that Var($C_n$) = 5/36

Comment: @Peter If you meant E$[X_i^2]=\frac 16$ and Var$(X_i)=\frac5{36}$, then yes.

Comment: yes, that is what I meant